# Spring Data Rest - Filter Association resources with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data-rest

Consider two entities `Entity` and `OtherEntity` exposed as `@RepositoryRestResource`, linked by a `@ManyToOne` relationship (an `Entity` may have several `OtherEntities`)

You want to use Spring Security to filter the collection resources, so you override their Repository's `Iterable<Entity> findAll()` function.

```
@RepositoryRestResource
@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends CrudRepository<Entity, Long> {
    @Override
    @PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'READ')")
    Iterable<Entity> findAll();
}
```

When invoking `GET /api/v1/entities`, or `GET /api/v1/otherEntities`, you get a result filtered by permission accordingly.

But when invoking their association resource, `GET /api/v1/entities/:id/otherEntities`, the list of `OtherEntity` elements retrieved is not filtered.

**What Repository function should be overridden so that the association resource gets filtered too?**

Or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as far as I am aware, there is no current mechanism to support this directly in Spring Data or JPA. (see: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-293)

It would definitely not be enough to override just repository method, as that only controls which Root of the Entity Hierarchy would be returned, in order to support this you'd have to filter each of the Mapped Entities...

If you are using hibernate under the hood this is theoretically possible by using [Hibernate Filters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-filter). So on your base Entity you'd have to add a filter to each of it's mapped Entities - but then, that won't play nicely with the default Spring Data Repository, so you have additional customization to do, for [example](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-hibernate-entity-level).

Unfortunately, this is not nearly as simple as one would hope :)

Comment: I knew I read about it somewhere, thank you for the ticket reference, bookmarking it this time :)
Will accept your answer if nothing better comes around.